# Remove trailing character(s) from string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing

What is an acceptable way to remove a particular trailing character from a string?

For example if I had a string:

```
> "item,"
```

And I wanted to remove trailing ','s only if they were ','s?

Thanks!

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Use a simple regular expression:

```
var s = "item,";
s = s.replace(/,+$/, "");
```

Comment: Just wanted to add: don't forget the backslash if you're replacing characters that have meanings to regular expressions (for example, '.').

Answer (score 22):

```
if(myStr.charAt( myStr.length-1 ) == ",") {
    myStr = myStr.slice(0, -1)
}
```

Comment: That `if` should probably be a `while`.

Comment: Ummmm why?? If the last character is a comma, slice the last character... I mean the most probable use case for this, is when you get an element from an array and make a JSON-ish text or something. You go like 'foreach element print element and ","' but then you realize, "dude, i have an extra ','" and wanna remove it.

Comment: He says ","s in plural, but I agree the title is confusing.

Comment: Yeah I think it depends on what he wants to achieve. @Dutrow pls explain

Comment: It doesn't hurt to use a while, It's really unlikely that his specific need involved *not* stripping a trailing comma.

Answer (score 15):

A function to trim any trailing characters would be:

```js
function trimTrailingChars(s, charToTrim) {
  var regExp = new RegExp(charToTrim + "+$");
  var result = s.replace(regExp, "");

  return result;
}

function test(input, charToTrim) {
  var output = trimTrailingChars(input, charToTrim);
  console.log('input:\n' + input);
  console.log('output:\n' + output);
  console.log('\n');
}

test('test////', '/');
test('///te/st//', '/');
```

Comment: How would it perfom on '///te/st//,'/'  ?

Comment: @TomasHesse - seems to work! I added a snippet above to test it out

Answer (score 1):

This will remove trailing non-alphanumeric characters.

```
const examples = ["abc", "abc.", "...abc", ".abc1..!@#", "ab12.c"];
examples.forEach(ex => console.log(ex.replace(/\W+$/, "")));

// Output:
abc
abc
...abc
.abc1
ab12.c
```